# calling block from another block

Tags: layout, blocks

I am calling a block left.phtml from my main store file like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
```

In the layout file this is described as:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="store_left" template="marketplace/storesearch/left.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Till now everything is working fine. Now I want to call another block from within this block:

```
    <div class="parlor-detail-top">
        <div class="shop_bakery">
            <a href="#" class="shop_now">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('rate_bakery'); ?>
    </div>
```

I have changed the layout file for this

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="store_left" template="marketplace/storesearch/left.phtml" />
    <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="rate_bakery" template="marketplace/storesearch/ratebakery.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

But this new block is getting included after the "left" block. How do I include this new block within the "left" block and not after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parent Child Tree Structure

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="store_left" template="marketplace/storesearch/left.phtml">
        <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="rate_bakery" template="marketplace/storesearch/ratebakery.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: It does not load the child block (rate_bakery) when I use this parent child tree structure. I checked the source also ... it just ignores this child block using this method.

Comment: Paste Your Layout XML here

Comment: You are calling in getChildHtml('rate_bakery') in phtml of store_left block right ?

Comment: Yes. I am calling it from within store_left block.

Comment: Okay just verify xml again and make sure you have added rate_bakery block as child of store_left block

Comment: <reference name="left">
   <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="store_left" template="marketplace/storesearch/left.phtml">
    <block type="marketplace/storeleft" name="rate_bakery" template="marketplace/storesearch/ratebakery.phtml"/>
   </block>
  </reference>